# Admin primary tabs completely disappeared

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm building a site in drupal 8, and I pushed my code from local to our development box, and on the development box, the Admin Primary Tabs have completely disappeared. Everywhere. The following is a screenshot of the issue.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB6Sp.png]

The code is version controlled (git), and the databases are identical. There are no outstanding configuration changes to synchronize either. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out what the issue is. Is there a settings somewhere I'm missing? I've tried logging out, clearing the cache, different browser. Nothing. I wanted to get a second option before submitting an issue report on drupal.org.

Answer (score 2):

@see [Where are the primary and secondary tab blocks?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214252/where-are-the-primary-and-secondary-tab-blocks/214471)

You probably installed the **minimal** profile. And although these blocks are part of the Seven theme they only get installed in the standard profile. Sounds a like a bug. As they rather should get installed during the installation of the theme instead of during the profile installation.

> Try this:
>
> Use Drush or Drupal console or the built-in Configuration
>   Synchronisation to export your current configuration. Then copy the
>   config files...
>
> core/profiles/standard/config/install/block.block.seven_local_actions.yml
>   core/profiles/standard/config/install/block.block.seven_page_title.yml
>   core/profiles/standard/config/install/block.block.seven_primary_local_tasks.yml
>   core/profiles/standard/config/install/block.block.seven_secondary_local_tasks.yml
>
> ... into your config folder - which is probably
>   /sites/default/files/config_[hashcode]/sync/. Then do a config import
>   (using one of those 3 tools above).

Comment: Right answer! Thanks! I ended up adding this to my config/optional folder of my profile: block.block.seven_breadcrumbs.yml block.block.seven_content.yml
block.block.seven_help.yml
block.block.seven_local_actions.yml
block.block.seven_login.yml
block.block.seven_messages.yml
block.block.seven_page_title.yml
block.block.seven_primary_local_tasks.yml
block.block.seven_secondary_local_tasks.yml
block.block.seven_page_title.yml
block.block.seven_primary_local_tasks.yml block.block.seven_secondary_local_tasks.yml

Answer (score 1):

I Don't know why the configuration are identical when they shouldn't, but I think that the admin theme does not have the "Primary tabs" blocks in header, you can check your production env Block layout  and see if infact the "Primary tabs" block is there (admin/structure/block/list/seven).

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the cache on the development server fixed the issue.